# Seeking comprehensive descriptions of tools in QGIS, SAGA, Orfeo, etc. toolboxes?

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, references, hydrology, taudem

There exists a large number of tools for QGIS (e.g. SAGA, GRASS, ORFEO etc.) - however none of these have sound description of the aim of the tool, the algorithm itself, differences to other similar tools and a hints for the interpretion of the result. How can I judge which tool to use if I do not know this essential background information?

This leads to a great problem that many people use sophisticated analyses but apply wrong (or only standard) parameters or thresholds as they do not know which parameter to adjust. ESRI provides simple explanations for their tools (also they seem not to be written by experts but programmers), taudem has useful description - It would be great to have similar descriptions for the other available opensource tools too!

I wish that the programmers, after working so hard could add half a page to describe the approach, add references, and explain (shortly) their parameters and the results and codes.

Where can I get background information on the different morphology/hydrology tools?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As it stands I think your question is too broad, and so I think you should edit it to focus it down to something that may be more answerable in a few paragraphs.  For example, if you ask for a "sound description of the aim of the tool, the algorithm itself, differences to other similar tools and a hints for the interpret[at]ion of the result" for just the tool that is the most important to you, it may well lead you to a source of such information about other tools.  Or, if not, then you can always research/ask about those separately.